# Serving an AngularJS app from Tomcat on localhost:8080

Tags: angularjs, tomcat7

I have an AngularJS application on my server that works fine when I request it from my Apache server but not when I request it from my Tomcat7 server.

The following request:

```
http://www.learnintouch.com/nitro-project/index.html
```

allows me to log in with the application login form and to view the application.

But the following request:

```
http://www.learnintouch.com:8080/nitro-project-rest/resources/index.html
```

pops up the browser HTTP authorization.

Here is my Spring Security configuration:

```
http
.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
.and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ADMINS + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.LOGIN).permitAll()
.and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated();
```

And the web configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/index.html").addResourceLocations("/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

When sending the request: http://www.learnintouch.com:8080/nitro-project-rest/resources/index.html the console output is:

```
2014-11-14 13:20:32,755 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'NITRo' processing GET request for [/nitro-project-rest/resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js] 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,756 DEBUG  [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,768 DEBUG  [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Did not find handler method for [/resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js] 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,771 DEBUG  [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Matching patterns for request [/resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js] are [/resources/**] 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,771 DEBUG  [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] URI Template variables for request [/resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js] are {} 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,771 DEBUG  [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapping [/resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@f60ab9]]] and 1 interceptor 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,771 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Last-Modified value for [/nitro-project-rest/resources/scripts/scripts.acefeb1b.js] is: -1 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,772 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'NITRo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,773 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] Successfully completed request 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,773 DEBUG  [ExceptionTranslationFilter] Chain processed normally 
2014-11-14 13:20:32,773 DEBUG  [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SimpleCORSFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@a379e4 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html'; against '/logout' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/utils/view/menu.html at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [BasicAuthenticationFilter] Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'undefined' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [ProviderManager] Authentication attempt using com.nsn.nitro.project.rest.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,137 DEBUG  [BasicAuthenticationFilter] Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: The login undefined and password could not match. 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,138 DEBUG  [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/admin/view/login.html at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SimpleCORSFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/admin/view/login.html at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/admin/view/login.html at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/admin/view/login.html at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@a379e4 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/admin/view/login.html at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [AntPathRequestMatcher] Checking match of request : '/resources/modules/admin/view/login.html'; against '/logout' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [FilterChainProxy] /resources/modules/admin/view/login.html at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [BasicAuthenticationFilter] Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'undefined' 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [ProviderManager] Authentication attempt using com.nsn.nitro.project.rest.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [BasicAuthenticationFilter] Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: The login undefined and password could not match. 
2014-11-14 13:20:33,146 DEBUG  [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: This is a follow up on my previous issue:

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490878/accessing-a-static-index-html-resource-in-a-spring-mvc-application

Comment: Could it be possible that, in the first case, you are passing through a HTTP module?
Because it is possible to see a redirect there, while in the second case it seems you are accessing directly to the Tomcat

Comment: @MichaelZucchetta What is that HTTP module thing ?

Comment: Sorry I think I read the post improperly.
Anyhow, I think that the correct URL is the following:
http://www.learnintouch.com:8080/nitro-project-rest/index.html
With the resources you are accessing it directly, making lose the context to your java application

Comment: I tried your suggested url http://www.learnintouch.com:8080/nitro-project-rest/index.html but it pops up the HTTP authentication window asking for credentials. And I now see it does the same for my url http://www.learnintouch.com:8080/nitro-project-rest/resources/index.html What I would like is to have the static resource served and not being asked for security credentials for any static resources.

Comment: what does the console show?

Comment: @EliteOctagon I edited the question to clean it up and reflect the latest configuration with the console output.

Comment: It all works fine when I disable the security configuration. But if the security described above is enabled then I get a 401 on all requests including the admins/login one. The security used to work and suddenly it stopped when I added a mapping in the servlet configuration.

Comment: The trouble was, my AngularJS interceptor was adding the Authorization header not only on REST urls but also on static resources urls like html templates and all. This was transparent when there resources were served by grunt but it became the issue when served by Tomcat.